# Internet in Ubuntu 14.04 goes fast and then slow

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have asked this question a few times before, but I unfortunately couldn't find an answer.

I have tried fixing my internet with Ubuntu 14.04 numerous times, but I think I will need a fix particular to my system.

It will go fast for a while, and then it will go really slow and not go back for a while.

I have an HP laptop:

Here is what it says when I run lshw:
Code:

```
description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
   description: Motherboard
   physical id: 0
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 3842MiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3520  @ 2.16GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 2159MHz
      capacity: 2159MHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms cpufreq
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: ValleyView SSA-CUnit
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 0c
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: ValleyView Gen7
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:106 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3050(size=8)
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 13
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:104 ioport:3048(size=8) ioport:305c(size=4) ioport:3040(size=8) ioport:3058(size=4) ioport:3020(size=32) memory:90914000-909147ff
    *-usb
         description: USB controller
         product: ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 0c
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:103 memory:90900000-9090ffff
    *-generic UNCLAIMED
         description: Encryption controller
         product: ValleyView SEC
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:90800000-908fffff memory:90700000-907fffff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 0c
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:107 memory:90910000-90913fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: ValleyView PCI Express Root Port
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=4096)
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: ValleyView PCI Express Root Port
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:90600000-906fffff ioport:90400000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 07
            serial: c4:34:6b:44:91:14
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:105 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90600000-90600fff memory:90400000-90403fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: ValleyView PCI Express Root Port
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:19 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:90500000-905fffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: 9c:d2:1e:6d:67:2c
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=3.13.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:19 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90500000-90503fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: ValleyView Power Control Unit
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: ValleyView SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 0c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:90915000-9091501f ioport:3000(size=32)
```

And this is iwconfig:

Code:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"HOME-2322"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 58:23:8C:68:23:22   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-16 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:55   Missed beacon:0
```

Please help!!

Comment: Sorry not really enough information to help.  You'll have to do a lot more monitoring and detective work as the problem may actually lie outside your domain with the ISP you are using.  You could have other interferences with other processes?  Your home networking equipment could be going bad.  Your ethernet cable could be going bad.  What about power fluctuation.  I hope that you are getting the point here that you need to investigate this a LOT more yourself from ALL aspects.  Just saying things are slow at times is not very helpful and will yield low quality answers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am going to start from all angles. I am going to take it to work to see if any issues arise

Comment: Remember to examine all the software interactions too, not just the hardware and external stuff.  That is helpful of course, but you might be having some CPU starvation problems too.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. On the bright side, I am learning a lot of new stuff about my computer lol. Quick question, what is CPU starvation?

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging your router non-stop (every second or faster) and see if it's getting any lag (delays).

Your router should always reply to you quickly, within maybe 2 or 3 ms. If it slows down at the same time as all your internet traffic does, I'd say that points to a wireless problem (reception) or a router problem (bogging down with too much p2p traffic can happen).

And if your router ping's never slow down (always 2-3 ms) then the delay is somewhere past your router.

Other ideas:

- Try a different wifi adapter
- Try a different router?
- Buy & install network/fibre optic cable?
- Buy faster internet access?

Could be a bug too, like this one http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2447-2/ "USN-2447-1 fixed vulnerabilities in the Linux kernel. Due to an unrelated regression TCP Throughput drops to zero for several drivers after upgrading."

Comment: Okay cool. I am going to start investigating it some more. Im taking it to work tomorrow to see if the problem extends there. Thanks for your help I appreciate it.